# How can I import one column in a table to another table on sql?

Tags: sql

I have the table

```
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
```

I want a new table with these values

```
| Col4 | Col5 | Col2 | Col6 |
```

With any values of col2 onto the new table

Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `select NULL, NULL col2, NULL from t`.

Answer (score 0):

If It Is Just About To Import All Data Of Col2 In Another Table ,Then 
Suppose TB1 has Columns (Col1 , Col2 , Col3)
and TB2 has Columns (Col4 , Col5 , Col2 , Col6)

Then Your Quert Would Be  Like This ,

```
Insert INTO TB2(Col2)(Select Col2 From TB1);
```

else 
Please Give More Specification Like You Want To Update Data That is Not In TB2 Like That.